# How can i customize GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to customize GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken() and GenerateEmailConfirmationToken() in ASP.NET Identity 2.
How to implement it?
I need to generate my custom token. Can I do it?

Comment: your question doesn't make any sense. Can you explain little more?

Comment: I need to generate my custom token. Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot except by replacing the complete ASP.NET identity code by yourself. The tokens are generated and validated according to [RFC 6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) with 6 digits used. You can refer to the source code [here](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can  reimplement the GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken as It's defined as a virtual method in Usermanager class .
By the way you must change the codes in class Rfc6238Authentication to customize the main functions it's been coded but you cannot change the code generated.
To attain this you should take [this](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs) class and(I mean copy/paste) to your project and modify it as you wish.
I guess you may need to alter otp life time. I'v done this.

as a clue :
The implementation in rfc6238 has a private static field named _timeStep with default value of 3 minutes :

```
private static readonly TimeSpan _timestep = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
```

You can change the behaviour of it to a property (remove readonly) :

```
    private static TimeSpan _timestep = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
```

and make the GenerateCode method more dynamic :

```
  public static int GenerateCode(SecurityToken securityToken, TimeSpan timeStep ,string modifier = null)
        {
            if (securityToken == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("securityToken");
            }
            _timestep = timeStep;
            // Allow a variance of no greater than 90 seconds in either direction
            var currentTimeStep = GetCurrentTimeStepNumber();
            using (var hashAlgorithm = new HMACSHA1(securityToken.GetDataNoClone()))
            {
                return ComputeTotp(hashAlgorithm, currentTimeStep, modifier);
            }
        }
```

**remember you must pass timeStep to ValidateCode method either to make sure validation works properly**

Comment: If you have done this, why not share your code as example? Motivational `You can do this` are nice, but not a real answer.

Comment: I intended to publish hole I done but I've done these for a company I must ask permission to share my code.
But you'r right I can show by an example.I'll edit my post